# Retrieving value of JSON object with string variable

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json data

```
var data={"mainVariants": [
        {
            "header": "Measure"
        },
        {
            "header": "Disposal"
        },
         {
            "header": "Stairs"
        },
         {
            "header": "Furniture"
        }
    ],
    "Measure": {}}

var val1=data.mainVariants[0].header;//returned as "Measure"
```

Now i want to retrieve data.val1.Pls help

Comment: Can you explain the question more about.

Comment: What data you want to retrieve? what is the expected output?

Comment: var data={"mainVariants": [{"header": "Measure"},{"header": "Disposal"},{"header": "Stairs"},{"header": "Furniture"}
    ],
    "Measure": {
     "1":"Value1"
     },
    "Disposal":{}
     etc....} 
       Now i want to find the header value of first mainVariants object.And with that i should get

    {
     "1":"Value1"
     },

so I did,

    var val1=data.mainVariants[0].header;  //I got the value "Measure"  correctly
    Now i want the corresponding object in data object.
So itried data.val1;And getting undefined value instead of
    {
     "1":"Value1"
     }

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can just do `var obj = data[val1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    var val1 = data.mainVariants[0].getString("header");